# Regular expression to find GridColumn in VS 2010 using C#

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

I need to find using the Ctrl-F functionality of VS2010, all the Telerik GridBoundColumn which are set to Visible="false".

```
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="FoodId" DataField="FoodId" Visible="false" />

or
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="FoodId" DataField="FoodId" Visible="false"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Pl can some provide me the Regular Expression to do the same.?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to EDIT -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files (or hit Ctrl + Shift + F). Check "Use Regular Expressions" in "Find Options" and "Display file names only" in "Result options"

Then on "Find what" introduce the following regex:

```
\<telerik\:GridBoundColumn[^>]@Visible="false"[^>]@
```

**Edit**: Taken into account the fact that the character for zero or more on VS2010 is `@` and that `<` and `>`must be escaped.

Comment: I would change the `.*` to `[^>]*` just to make sure it doesn't consume outside the tag

Comment: @Cemafor This is already handled by the non-greedy match (`*?`). On my test this consumes up to the closing tag. However, as I understand the question, this isn't so relevant as the OP just wants just to locate the controls, not to have any specific match.

Comment: I need to get list of ASPX files where we are using telerik:GridBoundColumn which are set to Visible=false.I need to use  Regular Expression in the Find and Replace Window of Visual Studio.
The above expression does not seems to work.Let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: @jignesh I checked the regex on VS and edited it according to the character that are used there. I also added instructions on how to display the list you want. Hope it helps...

Comment: @Cemafor I finally included your suggestion trying to make the expression match multiple lines until finding the closing tag

Comment: Thanks Camilo,it worked,only I had to escape the colon(:),
\<telerik\:GridBoundColumn[^>]@Visible="false"[^>]@